# Datastage Backup Configuration

Tags: backup, datastage

I'm using Infosphere Datastage & Quality Stage 8.5.
I need to know how to backup the whole datastage environment including DB2 files, configurations, etc. to prevent crash event on servers.
Please provide with the documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed instructions for backing up InformationServer 8.5 can be found here: [8.5 Backup](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_8.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.admin.burest.doc/topics/t_admin_backup_restore_super.html?lang=en)

Later versions of Information Server do have a backup and recovery tool. This tool works against multiple versions of the DataStage product (back to 8.5). See the following link: [InformationServer Backup/Recovery](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_9.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.admin.burest.doc/topics/a_installing_ismigration_tool_91.html%20InformationServer%20Backup/Recovery). Contact IBM support to obtain this tool.